# Prometheus metric to get POD runnig time

Tags: spring, kubernetes, prometheus

My app is deployed on kuebrentes and I want to track pods runnig time duration for example a pod started runnig at 9AM caus of scale up event and it get terminated at 10AM is there any metric with prometheus to get result for exmple

```
duration=60
```

i tried many metric like this one but none worked for me

```
sum by (namespace, pod) (
  (last_over_time(kube_pod_completion_time{pod="<pod_name>", namespace="<namespace>"}[1d]) - last_over_time(kube_pod_created{pod="<pod_name>", namespace="<namespace>"}[1d]))
  or
  (time() - kube_pod_created{pod="<pod_name>", namespace="<namespace>"})
)
```

Comment: It wouldn't hurt if you add to the question what you are going to do with this information, because there might be a better way than to look at pod's lifetime. For example you might like `process_uptime_seconds`, which is exposed by many frameworks (including spring with micrometer).

Comment: I didn't think such information might be valuable, but ok, I want to check how long each pod ran for in order to add that information in a dataset to detect a patter . For example, any pod that ran for under 20 minutes is a useless scaleup if every X day i have same behivour I will prevent that scale up event.

Comment: @anemyte  I think this work form me it but it gives me graph and from it I can see a terminated pod when it started and terminated but all this is visually  is there a way to make it JSON format ?   time() - kube_pod_start_time{namespace="default"}

Comment: Dunno about JSON, but I guess you need an instant query (not range). Here is a query you can start with: `max_over_time(process_uptime_seconds[1d:1h])`. It shows maximum registered `process_uptime_seconds` during last `1d`. Add `unless process_uptime_seconds` after it if you wish to remove currently running pods from the output.